# Kosher Pet Food

Tags: product-recommendation, animals, meat-and-milk, meat, dairy

It is prohibited to benefit from *basar b'chalav* (meat cooked with dairy) even by feeding it to one's animals.  (See e.g. [Chullin 115b](https://www.sefaria.org/Chullin.115b.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en); [Rambam Hilchoth Maachaloth Asuroth 9:1](https://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=5&hilchos=28&perek=9&halocha=1&hilite=))  Accordingly, are there concerns of *basar b'chalav*  with any of the commonly sold varieties of cat food or dog food in the United States? Are there specific, not well known ingredients (i.e. besides for the more obvious "beef" and "milk") to be on the look out for (e.g. "tallow", "whey", "casein")? Along these lines, are there any available lists of "recommended" or "not recommended" pet products?

Related: [Kashruth Issues with Dog Food?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/61867/kashruth-issues-with-dog-food)

Comment: Reader please note: (1) Answers here may be out of date by the time you read them. And, anyway, (2) you should ask your rabbi practical questions rather than relying on what you read on this site.

Comment: There are animal foods with a hechsher.

Comment: Yes, this is definitely a common problem. You need to read the ingredients.

Answer (score 1):

See Pischei Tshuvah D"H Tamei in Yoreh Deah 87:3 where he deals with the mechanics of your question. Additionally, D Wolf already touched upon the issue a bit.

This is what the Pischei Tshuvah there says:

טמאה. עי' בדגמ"ר שכ' וז"ל ובשר נבילה וכן חלב אסור לבשל בחלב מן התורה ולוקה על בישולו אבל באכילה אין בו איסור בב"ח וכ"ז מבואר ברמב"ם פ"ט ממ"א דין ו' ואמנם אם הוא אסור בהנאה אינו מבואר שם אבל בפי' המשניות פ"ג דכריתות מבואר שאינו אסור בהנאה ואף שלדברי התוס' בחולין ק"א בד"ה איסור כולל שכתבו שאיסור הנאה לא מיקרי איסור מוסיף אין הכרח לדברי הרמב"ם שם מ"מ לא מצינו להתוס' בפי' שיחלקו על דינו של הרמב"ם שהיכא שאינו אסור באכילה משום בב"ח אינו אסור בהנאה ולכן הסומך ע"ז במקום הפסד לא יפסיד עכ"ל ועי' פמ"ג בפתיחה שכתב דנקטינן דאסור בהנאה מן התורה ע"ש. (ועי' בתשובת ח"ס סי' צ"ב שנשאל ג"כ על ענין זה והביא דברי הגאון מעיל צדקה בספר כנפי יונה ר"ס פ"ז בעובדא שהאומנים עירבו חמאה בחלב לעשות מהם נרות כי היה החלב ביוקר ופשיט ליה לאוסרו בהנאה והגם כי מטעם תרבא י"ל לפי דנרות של חלב אינם עשוין מחלב הכליות והקרב לבד דמערבים בהם כמה מיני חלבים וקרומים שאין בהם כרת וא"כ שפיר איכא בב"ח משום תערובת דהני חלבים אך עכ"פ משום נבילה איכא דהא רוב בהמות של עובדי כוכבים אינם נשחטים ואפ"ה אסרו הגאון בהנאה ע"כ דס"ל אע"ג דאיסור אכילה ליכא מ"מ איסור הנאה איכא. והאריך בזה ומסיק דודאי המורה ובא כהגאון דגמ"ר אין מזחיחים אותו אבל אי קמי דידי אתי אני אוסר כהגאון כנפי יונה הנ"ל וכן משמע בהרבה גדולי האחרונים. ואפי' להדגמ"ר הוא לא מיירי מהנאת הדליק' אבל נר קרוזי"ל להדליקו בידים יש לחוש למבשל בב"ח שהטפה שסביבות השלהבת מתבשלת ואף דלענין שבת לא חשיב בישול בכה"ג אך לענין בב"ח אפשר דהוי בישול. וכתב עוד אמנם נר קרוזי"ל שנאסר כנ"ל ונתערב באחרים פשוט שבטל דאין כאן דבר שבמנין אלא דוקא נר חנוכה שבכל לילה מונין מנין הנרות למצותו ע"ש. ועי' בתשובת שבו"י ח"א סי' ס'):

Summary/Translation:

The P”Tsh says: See the Dagul M’rvava who writes: Its Assur M'diorisa due to Basar Bchalav to M’vashel Chelev/Nevelah with Chalav, and one who does so gets Malkus. However, to now eat the mixture  isn't an Issur Deorisa of Basar Bchalav, therefore you wouldn't get Malkus. The Rambam explains this, there's no Issur Bishul by Nevelah/Chelev, therefore when you're M’vasheling it with Chalav you're oiver on BB”ch and deserve Malkus. Whereas you wouldn't get Malkus for eating the Nevelah/Chelev mixed with Chalav due to BB”ch, since the Issur to eat Nevelah/Chelev exists, hence the concept: Ayn Issur Chal al Issur. Now, in a case of BB”ch Nevelah/Chelev the Rambam says it's not Assur B'hana'ah. The reason being: because Ayn Issur Chal Al Issur, the Issur of Hana'ah is learnt out from Achilah, therefore since there's no Issur of Achilas BB”ch by Nevelah/Chelev due to Ayn Issur Chal Al Issur (since they're Assur M'diorisa by themselves), therefore there's no Issur of Hana'ah by Achilas BB”ch Nevelah/Chelev. Tosfos doesn't seem to argue with the Rambam, concluding by saying in a place where's it's not Assur B’achila it's also not Assur B'hana'ah, therefore B’makom Hefsed Lo Yafsed. The Pri”mg says we learn that BB”ch is Assur B'hana'ah M'diorisa. See the Sh”t Chasam Sofer where he brings the Mi’el Tzedakah in the sefer Kanfei Yonah who says: Workers that'd make candles out of Butter and Chelev are Assur B'hana'ah. Since the candles made out of Chelev aren’t legit Chelev (chiyuv kares), therefore it's an issue of BB”ch. Now, there's no Issur of Achilas BB”ch D’orisa, there's still an Issur Hana'ah here because most meat from goyim is nevelah, so even though there's no Issur BB”ch D’orisa B’achilah, there's still an Issur BB”ch D’orisa B'hana'ah. Says the Chasam Sofer, if you pasken like the Dagul M’rvava then we're not Mazchichim you, but I And my others pasken L’chumrah that it'd be Assur BB”ch B'hana'ah. Even the Dagul M’rvava is only talking about getting Hana'ah from the flame of the candle, but to get Hana'ah from a Kruziel (where you're madlik it b’yadim) the Dagul M'rvava would be Choshesh for Bishul BB”ch. However, if Kruziel is M’sarev with with Acherim then it's pashut that it's batul because there's no min bmino here, whereas by Chanukah candles there is a Minyan. E”Sh.

Answer (score 0):

First off the only איסור הנאה is if they are cooked together. In addition   since אין איסור חל על איסור and probably the meat is not kosher meat there is no איסור הנאה either. See [Shulchan Arukh, Yoreh De'ah Siman 87 Seif 3](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.87.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> אינו נוהג אלא בבשר בהמה טהורה בחלב בהמה טהורה אבל בשר טהורה בחלב טמאה או בשר טמאה בחלב טהורה **מותרי' בבישול ובהנאה** ובשר חיה ועוף אפילו בחלב טהורה מותר בבישול ובהנאה

> The law only applies with meat from a pure [kosher] animal and milk from a pure animal, but meat of a pure animal in milk that is impure, or meat from an impure animal in pure milk, **is permitted to cook and benefit from.** Meat of a wild animal and of fowl, even in milk which is pure, is permitted to cook and benefit from; and even eating is only prohibited rabbinically.

(See also [Mishneh Torah Maakhalot Asurot 9:3](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/968265/jewish/Maachalot-Assurot-Chapter-9.htm#v3))

I also think that it is likely that בשר העומד לאכילת בהמה there is not prohibition of cooking it. But that's a little more difficult.

Comment: Why probably the meat is from a non kosher animal? Is beef not used often?

Comment: If the meat were from a non-kosher animal, there would be no problem of feeding it to a dog, since the cooking is only prohibited midirabanan. The answer seems to mean that the meat is nevaila, from a non-slaughtered animal.

Comment: 1. The rule "*ein issur chal al issur*" (prohibitions don't stack) isn't true by an "*issur mosif*" (more restrictive prohibition) such as *basar b'chalav* which is also an *issur hanaah* (prohibition of benefit); 2. As noted by the other commenters, the rule you cite from the Shulchan Aruch is regarding nonkosher/impure *species* - however, improperly slaughtered beef, goat, or lamb (neveila or treifa) can still become biblical *basar b'chalav*.  This is certainly a very prevalent ingredient in pet food - e.g. https://www.chewy.com/s?query=beef&nav-submit-button=

Comment: @DanielWolf that's only if you hold like the Rambam..